# getting 0>=0 while running program

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008

I run this code

```
public void loadtwo()
{
    try{
        String query="SELECT Grade.GradeName, [Group].GroupName, AcademicInfo.EntranceYear, Semester.SemesterName, AcademicRank.AcademicRankName, Others.OthersName, AcademicInfo.AcademicInfoID,AcademicInfo.Major, AcademicInfo.Department\n "+
                "FROM AcademicInfo INNER JOIN\n" +
                "AcademicRank ON AcademicInfo.AcademicRankID = AcademicRank.AcademicRankID INNER JOIN\n" +
                "Grade ON AcademicInfo.GradeID = Grade.GradeID INNER JOIN\n" +
                "[Group] ON AcademicInfo.GroupID = [Group].GroupID INNER JOIN\n" +
                "Others ON AcademicInfo.OthersID = Others.OthersID INNER JOIN\n" +
                "Semester ON AcademicInfo.SemesterID = Semester.SemesterID";
        DBlabprj.rs=DBlabprj.stmt.executeQuery(query);
        int i=0;
        while(DBlabprj.rs.next())
        {
            edutbl.setValueAt(DBlabprj.rs.getString("GradeName"),i,0);
            edutbl.setValueAt(DBlabprj.rs.getString("GroupName"),i,1);
            edutbl.setValueAt(DBlabprj.rs.getInt("EntranceYear"),i,2);
            edutbl.setValueAt(DBlabprj.rs.getString("SemesterName"),i,3);
            edutbl.setValueAt(DBlabprj.rs.getString("AcademicRankName"),i,4);
            edutbl.setValueAt(DBlabprj.rs.getString("OthersName"),i,5);
            edutbl.setValueAt(DBlabprj.rs.getInt("AcademicInfoID"),i,6);
            edutbl.setValueAt(DBlabprj.rs.getString("Major"),i,7);
            edutbl.setValueAt(DBlabprj.rs.getString("Department"),i,8);

            i++;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and I get this error:

> 0>=0

I can't understand what's wrong, when I remove the [] from Group I get this error:

> Incorrect Syntax near the word 'Group'

Comment: Replace `\n` by spaces in your query. And when you get an error copy the full stacktrace.

Comment: `GROUP` is a reserved word, which would explain your second error.

Comment: `Group` is a reserved keyword hence the error if you remove the brackets. Better try a different name.

Comment: The first error is a `java` error, unless I am mistaken: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, which could indicate that the SQL query returns an empty set.

Comment: I replaced \n with space but the 0>=0 error is still showing

Comment: Run the query directly against the database. If it runs fine, and returns rows, then you have a problem in the `java` code, otherwise it is a `sql` issue that needs to be fixed.

Comment: I added the java code to add rows automatically and now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

The second error is due to the fact that group is a keyword for T-SQL , so you can try to alias the table with some other variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have remove /n from your query and replace spaces use this one. Group is a reserved keyword but it will not create an error if it is inside the brackets. Better try a different name.

```
String query="SELECT Grade.GradeName, [Group].GroupName, AcademicInfo.EntranceYear, Semester.SemesterName, AcademicRank.AcademicRankName, Others.OthersName, AcademicInfo.AcademicInfoID,AcademicInfo.Major, AcademicInfo.Department  "+
                       "FROM AcademicInfo INNER JOIN " +
                       "AcademicRank ON AcademicInfo.AcademicRankID = AcademicRank.AcademicRankID INNER JOIN " +
                       "Grade ON AcademicInfo.GradeID = Grade.GradeID INNER JOIN " +
                       "[Group] ON AcademicInfo.GroupID = [Group].GroupID INNER JOIN " +
                       "Others ON AcademicInfo.OthersID = Others.OthersID INNER JOIN " +
                       "Semester ON AcademicInfo.SemesterID = Semester.SemesterID";
```

JTable columns start with 1 not with 0 so make `int i=1`;

```
edutbl.setValueAt(DBlabprj.rs.getString("GradeName"),i,0);
```